# webpack less loader override variables for node_modules

Tags: less, webpack

I have the following project structure:

- Proj.A: Repo with all less files (styles, mixins, variables, etc.)
- End project

  - Requires Proj.A
  - Has `config.less` which sets less @variables defined on Proj.A
  - Expect all the components below that also requires Proj.A to get the override values set in `config.less`
- Components (installed in End Project through `npm install`)

  - also requires Proj.A for less files (styles, mixing, variables, etc.)
  - requires its style through `js`, like `require('index.less')`
  - if variables defined in Proj.A are not override it uses the default values.

To simplify better, there is an example:

**Proj.A**

```
/*index.less*/

// declare all my variables
@bg-color: pink
```

**Component**

```
/* component.js */    
require('component.less')


/* component.less */    
@import '~projA/index.less'
```

**End Project**

```
/* index.js */    
require('config.less')
var myComponent = require('component')

/* config.less */    
@import '~projA/index.less'
@bg-color: blue
```

**webpack config** (it's a super simple webpack config, the only special thing is the less loader)

```
{
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.less$/,
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('css?sourceMap!less?sourceMap&strictMath')
      }
    ]
}
```

I expect that if I require `Component` isolated it should get a `@bg-color: pink`. But if it's required from `End Project` it should get a `@bg-color: blue`.

For now it aways get `pink`. Is there a way to tell `webpack | less-loader` to not bundle separately or have some kind of association with specific node_modules. I'd like to know how can I solve this problem, perhaps creating a new `loader` ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very simple solution if you control all parts (maybe a little hacky):

**Component**

```
/* component.js */    
require('component.less')

/* component.less */    
@import '~projA/index.less'
@import (optional) "@{THEME}"; /* if optional works, not tested */
```

**End Project**

```
/* index.js */    
var myComponent = require('component')

/* config.less */
@bg-color: blue
```

**webpack config**

```
{
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.less$/,
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('css?sourceMap!less?{"modifyVars":{"THEME":"\'' + path.resolve('config.less') + '\'"}}')
      }
    ]
}
```

Comment: I tried this code but got the error `module build failed: variable @theme is undefined`

Answer (score 0):

Without your webpack configuration, it is hard to tell what you're doing exactly, so I can only tell you what I know.

What I've done in the past is used a chained loader for my styles (style!css!less).  The style-loader has a nifty piece of functionality in it for "reference-counted styles" or as I like to call them useables.

The idea is that your components can "use" and "unuse" less files and the webpack style-loader will add/remove these less files from the DOM as needed so you have a little more control over what styles are loaded and not loaded.

[See this github page](https://github.com/webpack/style-loader#reference-counted-api) for some more information.

Comment: I added the config, I'm using extract text plugin and not style. What I want is to tell less-loader | webpack to get all `.less` files and bundle | compile | convert it considering my **End Project** overrides.